# How can i remove unwanted box chracters on my page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

There are boxes on the bottom of my page. I looked at the html and css files, i could not see.

how can i find where these characters come from ? how can i detect it from chrome browser ?

You can see codes from here http://codepen.io/tntpcx/pen/zBORMV

You can see chrome dev tools images below and one of my css files.

[image]

[image]

My css files

```
@CHARSET "utf-8";

/*
Name: Sliding Login Panel with jQuery 1.3.2
Author: Jeremie Tisseau
Author URI: http://web-kreation.com/
Date: March 26, 2009
Version: 1.0
*/

/***** clearfix *****/
.clear {clear: both;height: 0;line-height: 0;}
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
.clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}

/* Panel Tab/button */
.tab {
    background: url(../images/tab_b.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    height: 42px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.tab ul.login {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    height: 42px;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
    right: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.tab ul.login li.left {
    background: url(../images/tab_l.png) no-repeat left 0;
    height: 42px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.tab ul.login li.right {
    background: url(../images/tab_r.png) no-repeat left 0;
    height: 42px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.tab ul.login li {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(../images/tab_m.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}

.tab ul.login li a {
    color: #15ADFF;
}

.tab ul.login li a:hover {
    color: white;
}



.tab a.open, .tab a.close2 {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    /* width: 150px; */
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
}

.tab a.open {background: url(../images/bt_open.png) no-repeat left 0;}
.tab a.close2 {background: url(../images/bt_close.png) no-repeat left 0;}
.tab a:hover.open {background: url(../images/bt_open.png) no-repeat left -19px;}
.tab a:hover.close2 {background: url(../images/bt_close.png) no-repeat left -19px;}

/* sliding panel */
#toppanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;  
    /* background: #ff4f4f;  this is for pink color*/
    /* background: lightskyblue; */
    background : #701827;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}

#panel h1 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

#panel h2{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

#panel p {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#panel a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #15ADFF;
}

#panel a:hover {
    color: white;
}

#panel a-lost-pwd {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#panel .content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#panel .content .left {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}

#panel .content .right {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

#panel .content form {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#panel .content label {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    clear: both;
    width: 280px;
    display: block;
}

#panel .content input.field {
    border: 1px #1A1A1A solid;
    background: white;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    height: 16px;
}

#panel .content input:focus.field {
    background: #545454;
}

/* BUTTONS */
/* Login and Register buttons */
#panel .content input.bt_login,
#panel .content input.bt_register {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#panel .content input.bt_login {
    width: 74px;
    background: transparent url(../images/bt_login.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#panel .content input.bt_register {
    width: 94px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent url(../images/bt_register.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#panel .lost-pwd {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    clear: right;
    padding: 15px 5px 0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color : lightblue;
}








/*
*   RESET
*/
*{
    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
    /*margin: 0;*&
    /* outline: none; */
    /* padding: 0; */
}

*:after,
*:before {
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}



#closepopup.close {
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: .2em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    right: 1.25rem;
}

#closepopup.close:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
}




#closepopupLost.closeLost {
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: .2em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    right: 1.25rem;
}

    #closepopupLost.closeLost:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }



#closepopupprof.closeprof {
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: .2em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    right: 1.25rem;
}

    #closepopupprof.closeprof:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

#closepopuporder.closeorder {
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: .2em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    right: 1.25rem;
}

    #closepopuporder.closeorder:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }   
/*
*   LOG-IN BOX
*/
div.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    div.overlay > div.login-wrapper {
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 700px;
    }

        div.overlay > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 24px;  
            position: relative;
        }

            div.overlay > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content > h3 {
                color: rgb(0,0,0);

                margin: 0 0 1.25em;
                padding: 0;
            }




div.overlayLost {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    div.overlayLost > div.login-wrapper {
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 700px;
    }

        div.overlayLost > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 24px;  
            position: relative;
        }

            div.overlayLost > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content > h3 {
                color: rgb(0,0,0);

                margin: 0 0 1.25em;
                padding: 0;
            }
















div.overlayprof {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    div.overlayprof > div.login-wrapper {
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 700px;
    }

        div.overlayprof > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 24px;  
            position: relative;
        }

            div.overlayprof > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content > h3 {
                color: rgb(0,0,0);

                margin: 0 0 1.25em;
                padding: 0;
            }







div.overlayorder {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    div.overlayorder > div.login-wrapper {
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 700px;
    }

        div.overlayorder > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 24px;  
            position: relative;
        }

            div.overlayorder > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content > h3 {
                color: rgb(0,0,0);

                margin: 0 0 1.25em;
                padding: 0;
            }









/*
*   FORM
*/

/* form label {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    display: block; 
    margin: .75em 0;    
} */

/*  form input[type="text"],
    form input[type="password"],
    form textarea {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        display: block;

        margin: 6px 0 12px 0;
        padding: .25em .55em;   
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        width: 50%;
    } */

    .loginfrm
    {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        display: block;

        margin: 6px 0 12px 0;
        padding: .25em .55em;   
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        width: 90%;
    }


    .signupfrm
    {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        /* display: block; */ 

        margin: 0px 0 12px 0;
        padding: .25em .55em;   
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .captcha
    {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        /* display: block; */ 

        margin: 6px 0 12px 0;
        padding: .25em .55em;   
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        width: 60%;
    }


    form input[type="text"]:focus,

    form input[type="password"]:focus,
    form textarea:focus,
    form select:focus { 
        border-color: #4195fc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 8px #4195fc;
    }

        form input[type="text"]:invalid:focus,
        form input[type="password"]:invalid:focus,
        form textarea:invalid:focus,
        form select:invalid:focus { 
            border-color: yellow;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 8px rgb(248,250,0);
        }

form button {
    background-color: #ff4f4f;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);

    padding: .55em .9em;
    transition: all 400ms ease; 
}

    form button:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }



.reset {
    background-color: #ff4f4f;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);

    padding: .55em .9em;
    transition: all 400ms ease; 
}

    .reset:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.overlayLink {
color: black;
}   


.overlayLinkLost {
color: black;
}   


.overlayLinkprof {
color: black;
}



.overlayLinkorder {
color: black;
}







 .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;

        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }



    .visitor
    {
    text-align:right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:20px
    }


    .grey 
    {
    color:lightblue;
    }













            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssorb05 div           (normal)
            .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .av           (active)
            .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
                background: url(../images/b05.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .jssorb05 div {
                background-position: -7px -7px;
            }

                .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover {
                    background-position: -37px -7px;
                }

            .jssorb05 .av {
                background-position: -67px -7px;
            }

            .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover {
                background-position: -97px -7px;
            }



            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 12 css */
            /*
            .jssora12l              (normal)
            .jssora12r              (normal)
            .jssora12l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora12rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora12l, .jssora12r, .jssora12ldn, .jssora12rdn {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(../images/a12.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .jssora12l {
                background-position: -16px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12r {
                background-position: -75px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12l:hover {
                background-position: -136px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12r:hover {
                background-position: -195px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12ldn {
                background-position: -256px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12rdn {
                background-position: -315px -37px;
            }
        .left right {

}

#box {

}

html body div div div div form {

}
```

Comment: please provide link of your website..

Comment: unfortunately :( , i have not host for this site yet. if i upload a host, i can give a link. how can i detect this from chrome browser ?

Comment: bro please provide link or working fiddle.

Comment: i think, its not for your css.plz insert your html code instead of your css.
or are you using jquery or js?

Comment: this is because of some of you js plugin...figure it out or provide us something

Comment: i added codepen , you can see boxes at bottom of the page.

Comment: i found. these characters are not seen on my ide (eclipse) , i removed spaces on that region of the page, then these boxes are gone. thank you very much friends.

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the end of you html. Just remove it...
(in your codepen it's on line 314, added after the closing div-tag